# Does 'saṁsaṭṭha' mean "arise together"?

Tags: pali

I read this statement in an answer:

> Cittasaṁsaṭṭhā means arising together because it is described in the
> same canon "idaṃ sukhaṃ imāya pītiyā sahagataṃ hoti sahajātaṃ
> saṃsaṭṭhaṃ sampayuttaṃ". "sahajātaṃ saṃsaṭṭhaṃ sampayuttaṃ" in this
> context is called Vevacana in VevacanaHara.

Generally, the word 'saṁsaṭṭha' is translated as 'co-joined' or 'mixed', as follows:

> But when they’re separated from the Teacher or a spiritual companion
> in a teacher’s role, they **mix closely** with monks, nuns, laymen, and
> laywomen; with rulers and their ministers, and with teachers of other
> paths and their followers.
>
> Yato ca kho so vapakassateva satthārā, vapakassati garuṭṭhāniyehi
> sabrahmacārīhi, so **saṁsaṭṭho** viharati bhikkhūhi bhikkhunīhi upāsakehi
> upāsikāhi raññā rājamahāmattehi titthiyehi titthiyasāvakehi.
>
> As they **mix closely**, they become intimate and loose, spending time
> chatting, and so lust infects their mind.
>
> Tassa **saṁsaṭṭhassa** vissatthassa pākatassa bhassamanuyuttassa viharato
> rāgo cittaṁ anuddhaṁseti.
>
> https://suttacentral.net/an6.60/en/sujato

> These are the five drawbacks for a mendicant who visits families for
> too long, **mixing closely** with them.”
>
> Ime kho, bhikkhave, pañca ādīnavā kulūpakassa bhikkhuno ativelaṁ
> kulesu **saṁsaṭṭha**ssa viharato”ti.
>
> https://suttacentral.net/an5.226/en/sujato

> “Wisdom and consciousness—
>
> “Yā cāvuso, paññā yañca viññāṇaṁ—
>
> are these things **mixed** or separate?
>
> ime dhammā **saṁsaṭṭhā** udāhu visaṁsaṭṭhā?
>
> Feeling, perception, and consciousness—
>
> “Yā cāvuso, vedanā yā ca saññā yañca viññāṇaṁ—
>
> are these things **mixed** or separate?
>
> ime dhammā **saṁsaṭṭhā** udāhu visaṁsaṭṭhā?
>
> https://suttacentral.net/mn43/en/sujato

Does 'saṁsaṭṭha' mean "arise together"? How can the terms "arise together" & "mixed" be reconciled or, otherwise, differentiated?

Answer (score 2):

It's depending on each context of Tipitaka.

The question's quote is from [this topic](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/45455/can-abhidhamma-be-reconciled-with-sutta-citta-vinnana), which quoting saṁsaṭṭha from Abhidhamma canon in the section which saṁsaṭṭha meaning "arise together", so it means arise together in that context.

It's depending on the canon author's mind while he was writing, not the reader's opinion. And the author's mind appear on the text's context, not reader's opinion.

If the reader craves on the only one word's meaning, he can't read even a word Buddha in Tipitaka because there are many same word with difference meaning there.  For the example, the word "buddha" also have many meaning in Tipitaka and some meaning is not enlightenment, such as [SuppaBuddha](https://suttacentral.net/ud5.3/en/anandajoti) which is only name gotten before his enlightenment, not refer to enlightenment.

Comment: Yes, the meaning of words can vary according to context. The mistake would be to fix on one meaning, and then try to force that meaning into other contexts. Translation requires a flexible approach.